# How can I fetch the record for 2018 only by php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to fetch the list they don't have an action in 2019 (they should have the only action before Jan 2019). 
For different list, there is different array with the timestamp.

Here is one array for a list.
(its name list1)

```
Array
(
    [list] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [action] => open
                    [timestamp] => 2019-04-18T18:03:24+00:00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [action] => click
                    [timestamp] => 2018-12-18T18:03:24+00:00
                )

        )
)
```

(So, in this case, that record should not print because it has the action in 2019 )

There is a different array for other lists

(its name list2)

```
 Array
    (
        [list] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [action] => open
                        [timestamp] => 2018-04-18T18:03:24+00:00
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [action] => open
                        [timestamp] => 2018-03-1T18:03:24+00:00
                    )

            )
    )
```

(In this case, this record print because it has no action in 2019)

What I am doing to achieve this:

```
$date1 = "2018-12-31T024:00:00+00:00"; 
foreach ($list['list'] as $e) {
 if($date1<$e['timestamp'])
   echo $e['action'];
}
```

But it is not displaying the records before 2019 only. Please guide me how I achieve this.

Comment: is this coming from a database? why not do it from there instead

Comment: It is not coming from db it is coming from api

Comment: what about the API though?, any decent API should at least give you some options on what to fetch. it would be impractical to load all of the data at once

Comment: but yeah, for the purposes of filtering an array, yes its possible, its `array_filter` :D or you could stick with `foreach`, convert both dates into *unix timestamp* and compare, or use *`DateTime`* classes

Comment: I got your point but what should be the condition?

Comment: Convert the string representation of the date to a `DateTime` object or UNIX timestamp. Then checking what year it is should be pretty simple…

Comment: So you want to check if that whole `list` sub-array contains _any_ item with a date in 2019, and then you don’t want to output the _whole_ `list`? Then you need to loop over the items in that list, and use a boolean flag to determine the final state after you evaluated _all_ items.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to use `DateTime`, not a string here. Finaly, hope I got it right:

```php
$latestDate = new \DateTime('2019-01-01'); 
records = $api->get("record/members?offset=0&count=20");
foreach ($records['members'] as $member) {
     $hash = md5($member['email_address']);
     $lists = $api->get("record/members/$hash/list");

     foreach ($lists['list'] as $action) {
         if(new \DateTime($action['timestamp']) >= $latestDate) {
             continue 2;
         }
      }
      var_dump($lists['list']);
}
```

You can also use [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php) for this and replace `var_dump` as you wish.

Comment: thanks for it but I want to skip that array if it has a date of 2019.

Comment: @Johny just post the expected output in your question.

Comment: I've edited the question, I want to skip list1 because it has a date of 2019 I want to print only list2 array because it has no date in 2019

Comment: I want to skip whole array if it has a date in 2019.

Comment: Please, try to express your thoughts more clear. What is you input? Array of arrays? Two array? What should be in the output? Array of arrays with no action below 2019? You can make an example here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: I have an array for users, after the loop I am getting the sub-array of user list (as it is my question). Each sub-array contains many records of timestamp and actions for a user. Now I want to show only those subarray which has the timestamp of the year 2018 only, if in subarray there is both 2018 and 2019 (like list1 as in my question) I want to skip this array and just want to print those subarrays which has the all timestamp of the year 2018 only (like list2).

Comment: Then an answer is here, just skip or filter empty array after the function run.

Comment: How can I do that? Please let me know.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f29bf8144d842a8958c9cd31fbfa30f8e10b11e9

Comment: This is the same case on my end too, I just want to filter those sub-arrays which have all timestamp of 2018.

Comment: It feels like you are trolling me: post you code with fake api calls, how do you get the data and trying to filter it.

Comment: I am not trolling you, My question is simple: How can I filter only those subarrays which have all the timestamp of the year 2018? Here is fake api call
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2a67030eae7418a91bcb2073dbcf152c8d3cf7d0

Comment: Do you need to ouptut the whole `list` array, which subitems don't have any `timestamp` after 2019?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As you retrieve an array from your API you can simply use the FilterIterator class PHP natively provides. Have a look at the following example.

```
namespace App\Filter;

use DateTime;
use FilterIterator;
use Iterator;

class DateFilterIterator extends FilterIterator
{
    protected $filter;

    public function __construct(Iterator $iterator, $filter)
    {
        parent::__construct($iterator);
        $this->filter = $filter;
    }

    public function accept()
    {
        $entry = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        return (new DateTime($entry['timestamp']))->format('Y') !== $this->filter;
    }
}
```

This is our filter, which will iterator over the api response.

```
$object = new ArrayObject($apiResponse);

$iterator = new DateFilterIterator($object->getIterator(), 2018);
foreach ($iterator as $entry) {
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($entry);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

As we initialize our filter with the year 2018, we will retrieve the array entries with the timestamp, which fits the year 2018. With the FilterIterator class you can define the year and iterate over the api response over and over for different filter values. The filtering itself is executed in a simple foreach loop / on iteration.

If you want to filter for a specific date, you have to adjust the accept function of the filter class for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try I not tested code

```
function filterDate($date)
{


    $yearDate=date('Y', strtotime ($date['timestamp']));

    if($yearDate==2018)
    {
         return $date;

     }

}



$datesOnly2018=array_filter('filterDate',$list['list']);
```